# why is this code not returning anything?

Tags: python-3.x

I was coding a guessing game in python and i had a crash on my computer and now the code has somehow gone all over the place and now im not sure where each block goes the end result should be it outputting something along the lines off

Hello! What is your name?

Albert

Well, Albert, I am thinking of a number between 1 and 20.

Take a guess.

10

Your guess is too high.

Take a guess.

2

Your guess is too low.

Take a guess.

4

Good job, Albert! You guessed my number in 3 guesses!

```
print('Hello! What is your name?')

myName = input()
number = random.randint(1, 20)

print('Well, ' + myName + ', I am thinking of a number between 1 and 20.')


while guessesTaken < 6:

print('Take a guess.') # There are four spaces in front of print.

guess = input()

 guess = int(guess)



 guessesTaken = guessesTaken + 1


 if guess < number:
   print('Your guess is too low.') # There are eight spaces in front of print.



 if guess > number:

    print('Your guess is too high.')


 if guess == number:

     break


if guess == number:
 guessesTaken = str(guessesTaken)
 print('Good job, ' + myName + '! You guessed my number in ' + guessesTaken 
  + ' guesses!')





 if guess != number:

number = str(number)

 print('Nope. The number I was thinking of was ' + number)
```

Comment: Please correct your indentation

Comment: Please indent your code properly so we can help.

Answer (score 0):

I reindented the code properly, added one line (to initialize `guessesTaken`) and it seems to work now:

```
print('Hello! What is your name?')

myName = input()
number = random.randint(1, 20)

print('Well, ' + myName + ', I am thinking of a number between 1 and 20.')

guessesTaken=0
while guessesTaken < 6:

   print('Take a guess.') # There are four spaces in front of print.
   guess = input()
   guess = int(guess)
   guessesTaken = guessesTaken + 1

   if guess < number:
       print('Your guess is too low.') # There are eight spaces in front of print.

   if guess > number:
       print('Your guess is too high.')

   if guess == number:
       break

if guess == number:
    guessesTaken = str(guessesTaken)
    print('Good job, ' + myName + '! You guessed my number in ' + guessesTaken + ' guesses!')

if guess != number:
   number = str(number)    
   print('Nope. The number I was thinking of was ' + number)
```